# Open-Loop Gain and differential gain

Tags: operational-amplifier

Assuming an op-amp that is connected without any feedback.

Then in theory does Open-Loop Gain and differential gain convey the same information or am I missing something?

Comment: They are the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An op-amp is a two input device and is differential in that it is the difference voltage between the two inputs that is amplified. Theoretically, if both inputs are connected together and moved up and down with a voltage source, the output will stay stable.

This proves that it is a differential device and therefore, open-loop gain is the same as open-loop differential gain. Notice that I referred to "open loop differential gain" because I want to make it clear in what I'm talking about.